# text under image slider jumping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an image slider on my website, the problem is that when the slide changes, the div with text that is under it "jumps" up for a second. its caused because the height of div with slider is suddenly  0 (although I use fade out and fade in, so the next image should start appearing before the previous disappears completely) I tried to set image with the only alfa in the background, but it changed nothing. I could set the slider div height to certain size but that would cause it to not work properly on different screen sizes...

slider JS code:

```
function schowaj(){
                $("#slider").fadeOut(500);
            }

function zmienslajd(){
                numer++; if (numer>5) numer=1;

                var plik = "<img width=\"100%\" height=\"auto\" src= \"slajdy/" + numer + ".bmp\" />"

                document.getElementById("slider").innerHTML = plik;
                $("#slider").fadeIn(500);
                setTimeout("zmienslajd()",7000);
                setTimeout("schowaj()", 6500);
            }
```

slider html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8" style="margin:auto; width:100%; height:auto">
                <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly hack workaround, but you can change the `opacity` instead of using `fadeOut`; this way means you're not messing around with the `display` property. Change `schowaj` to:

```
function schowaj() {
    $("#slider").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500);
}
```

Then inside `zmienslajd`, change to:

```
$("#slider").animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 500);
```

Comment: It worked, everything is looking good now. What about the img that has it opacity changed to 0? Will it stay and if so if the page is loaded for some time, can it cause any troubles?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean. The `<img />` never has its opacity changed, only the `#slider` element.

Comment: You are right, nevermind. I thought that it adds another picture and makes the previous one opacity 0, but just as you said it makes slider opacity 0, changes img and backs to opacity 1